# BIRT 4.4 version ScriptOrFnNode not found error

Tags: eclipse, birt

1. created a pallet
2. created a data source and connected
3. created the data set and interlinked it with pallet
4. Clicked "view reports" throws belo error

Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/mozilla/javascript/ScriptOrFnNode
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQuery.(PreparedQuery.java:100)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedDataSourceQuery.(PreparedDataSourceQuery.java:75)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedOdaDSQuery.(PreparedOdaDSQuery.java:76)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.PreparedQueryUtil.newInstance(PreparedQueryUtil.java:211)
at org.eclipse.birt.data.engine.impl.DataEngineImpl.prepare(DataEngineImpl.java:426)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:473)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.data.adapter.impl.DataRequestSessionImpl.prepare(DataRequestSessionImpl.java:673)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(AbstractDataEngine.java:226)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.DteDataEngine.doPrepareQuery(DteDataEngine.java:272)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.data.dte.AbstractDataEngine.prepare(AbstractDataEngine.java:182)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.executor.ReportExecutor.execute(ReportExecutor.java:122)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.emitter.ReportEmitterExecutor.execute(ReportEmitterExecutor.java:71)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.dup.SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.execute(SuppressDuplciateReportExecutor.java:42)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.wrap.WrappedReportExecutor.execute(WrappedReportExecutor.java:60)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.internal.executor.l18n.LocalizedReportExecutor.execute(LocalizedReportExecutor.java:61)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.presentation.ReportDocumentBuilder.build(ReportDocumentBuilder.java:234)
at org.eclipse.birt.report.engine.api.impl.RunTask.doRun(RunTask.java:269)
... 72 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode cannot be found by org.eclipse.birt.data_4.4.2.v201501161327
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:511)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:422)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:414)
at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:153)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
... 91 more

PS :-  using eclipse 2019-03 version for this

Any leads appreciated.

Comment: Using outdated Birt and Eclipse is a pretty bad idea. Please update before asking to not waste other people's time. The missing class can be found e.g. [here](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jopendocument/rhino/1.7R1) by searching Maven Central for [`fc:org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode`](https://search.maven.org/search?q=fc:org.mozilla.javascript.ScriptOrFnNode).